# Visual Studio 2013 forcing 64 DLL file into 32 bit application - how to fix this?

Tags: c++, opengl, visual-studio-2013

EDIT:

So, I fiddled around some more with dependency walker, and came across this incredibly frustrating fact: Visual Studio has been forcing a 64-bit DLL (msvcr120.dll / msvcp120.dll / glu32.dll) into the program. I tried to remove all libraries from my linker settings and send out an empty file (int main{return(0);}), but it still forced it in, giving me my error.

This basically means, that no matter what I compile - literally no matter what I compile - the program won't be able to run on other computers. It shouldn't be able to run on my own computer, either.

How to solve this issue?

EDIT END.

The problem is as follows: The program compiles and runs bug-free on my own PC. (Windows 7 64bit, program is 32 bit)

However, as soon as I transfer it to my brothers PC (Windows 8 64 bit) and one of my friends computers whose operating system I don't know, the program returns the following error: (0xc000007b).

So, I searched the interwebs for a solution, and I stumbled upon dependency walker. Here, I found some weird errors, indicating my DevIL is too old or so I believed.

[DepWalker1](http://puu.sh/acoGI/43147faf47.png)
[DepWalker2](http://puu.sh/acoP9/7fba80cd95.png)

So I tried to figure out how to compile DevIL manually in order to up from MSVCR80 to 120 - but to no avail.

So, the question is - how to compile DevIL manually via VS2013 32bit?

And a side question definitely is: What could my issue be?

Comment: It is really hard to guess what might be going on. The `msvc*` dlls are the C runtime libraries, you can't get rid of them via the linker input settings. You could link them statically, but that is not what you want. However, `glu32.dll` should not be linked in a "blank" project. Can you provide the `.vcxproj` file for that case?

Comment: Sure, but in what form and how? Do you want the raw code, or?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what was wrong.

When I send the program around to my friends, I manually send the DLL files. I wasn't aware of the difference in bits between system32 and sysWOW, so I just send some DLL files from system32, not knowing they were 64 bit.

AKA: Only send DLL files from either system32 OR sysWOW, as they do not share the same bit-type. (sysWOW for 32 bit, system32 for 64 bit)